# case statement only on column that is not null

Tags: sql, db2, case, where-clause

I'm writing a query that searches for people over 18 based on their birthdate and the current date. There are some instances where a person does not have a birth date in the database. For these people I just want to include them in my query and not perform the where clause on them. Is this possible? This is a db2 database

```
 select *
   from people i
where case when coalesce(i.birth_date,'') != '' then (i.birth_date < (SELECT CURRENT_DATE - 18 years from datetoday)) else '' end
```

This above query is what I tried but is throwing an error I'm not sure if it is the correct format. Or if what I'm trying to do is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a `CASE` just use `OR`:

```
select *
from people i
where (coalesce(i.birth_date) != '' AND (i.birth_date < (SELECT CURRENT_DATE - 18 years from datetoday)))
  OR  coalesce(i.birth_date) = ''
```

You can't return an expression with a `CASE` statement.

Comment: Just as an general FYI: case can only be used in the select part of an SQL query. In the where clause you can only use or.

Comment: @PeterSchuetze I don't know about db2, but you can certainly use `CASE` in the `WHERE` clause in some databases.

Comment: @GoatCO: I googled a bit and you are right about the case, my apologies. It is even accepted in db2. However, the case expression will take the place of a value (e.g. as in '(case when ... then ... else ...) > 15'). So that seems to be the issue with BS123's query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select *
from people i
where i.birth_date IS NULL OR i.birth_date < (SELECT CURRENT_DATE - 18 years from datetoday)
```

you can check if the birth_date is null or if they are over 18.